# main() method in array of objects

Tags: java

I have just started learning Java and going through Heard up series.  I see few examples where a class is created and has main in it and inside main, an object of the class is created. As main () is also part of the same class, is this ok? When you create a new Object, does it also create multiple copies of main () ? How does compiler decode this?

Sample code snippet explaining the problem

```
public class Hobbits {
    int size;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Hobbits h = new Hobbits[3];  
        // This is my point of concern. 
        // Here i create array of objects but each Object would have main class?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `main`-method is a `static` method. Static methods do not reference single objects, **think of them as methods of a class instead of an object** - they do not need any objects to work. [Read this for further explanations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: Thanks to all of them for answering this. To be more precise, i was thinking as main () is inside class, every Object of that class has reference to main (). I think this is not right...

Answer (score 0):

*"but each Object would have main class?"*
Your question is not so clear, but if you are asking if *every* class needs to have a main() method, then the short answer is **NO**. You can have a single main() in a separate class that calls all your other classes (Hobbit class, Wizard class, Elf class, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If your function/variable is `static`, it means there is only one instance of it, does not matter how many instances of your class you will create.

second thing, it will be more aesthetic, if you create separate class only for your main method

Comment: More than "aesthetic", I think having the main() in a separate class also marks the early beginnings of OP's first MVC. :)